One bar graph bar does not work in shiny app but works locally
I recently started using Rstudio to make an interactive web site. The user selects some values (number of span for the LOESS, number of months, months and/or days) and the system adds or subtracts the number of individuals. Then it displays it in a bar chart. The problem is that everything works fine on my machine, locally, but when I upload it to shinyapps.io one of the 4 bars that contains the graph does not change (neither adds nor subtracts, it does not “react”). It is the right bar, the other bars are modified and updated. I have no idea why and I can't find any errors in the log. I clarify that I “program” mainly by asking chatgpt. Here is a screenshot of how it reacts on my machine locally.
this is how the app starts:
(I only show the bar chart which does not work well.)

then I change the selection and it looks like this:
this is how it is modified locally:

this is the code in R:
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

df_datos = structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(14643, 14644, 14645, 14646, 14647, 14648, 14649, 14650, 14651, 14652, 14653, 14654, 14655, 14656, 14657, 14658, 14659, 14660, 14661, 14662, 14663, 14664, 
 14665, 14666, 14667, 14668, 14669, 14670, 14671, 14672, 14673, 14674, 14675, 14676, 14677, 14678, 14679, 14680, 14681, 14682, 14683, 14684, 14685, 14686, 14687, 14688, 14689, 14690, 14691, 14692, 14693, 14694, 14695, 14696, 14697, 14698, 14699, 14700, 14701, 14702, 14703, 14704, 14705, 14706, 14707, 14708, 14709, 14710, 14711, 14712, 14713, 14714, 14715, 14716, 14717, 14718, 14719, 14720, 14721, 14722, 14723, 14724, 14725, 14726, 14727, 14728, 14729, 14730, 14731, 14732, 14733, 14734, 14735, 14736, 14737, 14738, 14739, 14740, 14741, 14742, 14743, 14744, 14745, 14746, 14747, 14748, 14749, 14750, 14751, 14752, 14753, 14754, 14755, 14756, 14757, 14758, 14759, 14760, 14761, 14762, 14763, 14764, 14765, 14766, 14767, 14768, 14769, 14770, 14771, 14772, 14773, 14774, 14775, 14776, 14777, 14778, 14779, 14780, 14781, 14782, 14783, 14784, 14785, 14786, 14787, 14788, 14789, 14790, 14791, 14792, 14793, 14794, 14795, 14796, 14797, 14798, 14799, 14800, 14801, 14802, 14803, 14804, 14805, 14806, 14807, 14808, 14809, 14810, 14811, 14812, 14813, 14814, 14815, 14816, 14817, 14818, 14819, 14820, 14821, 14822, 14823, 14824, 14825, 14826, 14827, 14828, 14829, 14830, 14831, 14832, 14833, 14834, 14835, 14836, 14837, 14838, 14839, 14840, 14841, 14842, 14843, 14844, 14845, 14846, 14847, 14848, 14849, 14850, 14851, 14852, 14853, 14854, 14855, 14856, 14857, 14858, 14859, 14860, 14861, 14862, 14863, 14864, 14865, 14866, 14867, 14868, 14869, 14870, 14871, 14872, 14873, 14874, 14875, 14876, 14877, 14878, 14879, 14880, 14881, 14882, 14883, 14884, 14885, 14886, 14887, 14888, 14889, 14890, 14891, 14892, 14893, 14894, 14895, 14896, 14897, 14898, 14899, 14900, 14901, 14902, 14903, 14904, 14905, 14906, 14907, 14908, 14909, 14910, 14911, 14912, 14913, 14914, 14915, 14916, 14917, 14918, 14919, 14920, 14921, 14922, 14923, 14924, 14925, 14926, 14927, 14928, 14929, 14930, 14931, 14932, 14933, 14934, 14935, 14936, 14937, 14938, 14939, 14940, 14941, 14942, 14943, 14944, 14945, 14946, 14947, 14948, 14949, 14950, 14951, 14952, 14953, 14954, 14955, 14956, 14957, 14958, 14959, 14960, 14961, 14962, 14963, 14964, 14965, 14966, 14967, 14968, 14969, 14970, 14971, 14972, 14973, 14974, 14975, 14976, 14977, 14978, 14979, 14980, 14981, 14982, 14983, 14984, 14985, 14986, 14987, 14988, 14989, 14990, 14991, 14992, 14993, 14994, 14995, 14996, 14997, 14998, 14999, 15000, 15001, 15002, 15003, 15004, 15005, 15006, 15007, 15008, 15009, 15010, 15011, 15012, 15013, 15014, 15015, 15016, 15017, 15018, 15019, 15020, 15021, 15022, 15023, 15024, 15025, 15026, 15027, 15028, 15029, 15030, 15031, 15032, 15033, 15034, 15035, 15036, 15037, 15038, 15039, 15040, 15041, 15042, 15043, 15044, 15045, 15046, 15047, 15048, 15049, 15050, 15051, 15052, 15053, 15054, 15055, 15056, 15057, 15058, 15059, 15060, 15061, 15062, 15063, 15064, 15065, 15066, 15067, 15068, 15069, 15070, 15071, 15072, 15073, 15074, 15075, 15076, 15077, 15078, 15079, 15080, 15081, 15082, 15083, 15084, 15085, 15086, 15087, 15088, 15089, 15090, 15091, 15092, 15093, 15094, 15095, 15096, 15097, 15098, 15099, 15100, 15101, 15102, 15103, 15104, 15105, 15106, 15107, 15108, 15109, 15110, 15111, 15112, 15113, 15114, 15115, 15116, 15117, 15118, 15119, 15120, 15121, 15122, 15123, 15124, 15125, 15126, 15127, 15128, 15129, 15130, 15131, 15132, 15133, 15134, 15135, 15136, 15137, 15138, 15139, 15140, 15141, 15142), class = "Date"), `Numero de individuos` = c(3, NA, NA, 
          NA, NA, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 21, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, NA, NA, 31, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, 15, 7, NA, NA, 5, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, 4, 18, 26, 14, 28, 3, 5, 65, 25, 19, 31, NA, NA, 42, 52, 14, 22, 12, NA, NA, 20, NA, 35, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, 58, 35, 41, 49, NA, NA, 45, 41, NA, 30, 19, 4, NA, 65, 28, 67, 32, 25, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, NA, 12, NA, NA, 19, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 16, 16, 1, 18, 11, NA, NA, 12, 4, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23, 23, 13, 3, NA, 9, NA, 11, 1, 7, NA, NA, 26, 18, 15, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 38, 2, NA, NA, NA, 10, 20, 17, 19, 10, NA, NA, 8, 10, 7, 58, 22, NA, NA, 23, 54, 52, 41, 46, NA, NA, 57, NA, 70, 22, 47, NA, NA, NA, 65, 54, 42, NA, NA, NA, 29, NA, 68, 74, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, NA, NA, 40, NA, NA, 17, NA, NA, NA, 16, 24, 20, 28, 16, NA, NA, 36, NA, NA, NA, 30, 3, NA, 25, 38, NA, 20, 9, NA, NA, 49, 9, 62, 17, 40, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35, 31, NA, NA, NA, 40, 69, 7, 14, 16, 3, NA, 18, 22, NA, 17, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 39, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14, 6, 14, 11, NA, NA, 17, 6, 11, 7, 16, NA, NA, 12, 22, NA, 13, 26, NA, NA, 33, 9, 18, 30, 78, NA, NA, NA, 9, 12, 8, 16, NA, NA, 8, 5, 13, 13, 18, NA, NA, 9, 31, 30, 43, 28, NA, NA, 16, NA, 7, 11, 13, NA, NA, 7, NA, 10, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 7, 7, 2, 8, NA, NA, 6, 7, 9, 38, 8, NA, NA, 17, 14, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 7, 8, 16, NA, NA, 23, 21, 30, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15, 18, 15, 9, 12, NA, NA, 22, 17, 32, 28, 12, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 14, 8, NA, NA, 23, 15, 31, 14, 18, NA, NA, NA, 60, 69, 44, 39, NA, NA, 48, 8, 9, 11, 25), DiaSemana = c("miércoles", 
       "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo",  "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes",                "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado", "domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes")), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
  
# En lugar de cargar el archivo Excel, usaremos el dataframe unido
df <- df_datos

# Convertir la columna 'Fecha' a formato Date (ya está en formato correcto en tus datos)
df$Fecha <- as.Date(df$Fecha)

# Generar una secuencia completa de fechas entre el primer y el último día del dataframe
fechas_completas <- seq(min(df$Fecha), max(df$Fecha), by = "day")

# Unir con el dataframe original para rellenar los días faltantes
df_completo <- data.frame(Fecha = fechas_completas) %>%
  left_join(df, by = "Fecha")




# Convertir la columna 'Numero de individuos' a numérica
df_completo <- df_completo %>%
  mutate(`Numero de individuos` = as.numeric(`Numero de individuos`))

# Agregar columna con el día de la semana en letras (en español)
df_completo$DiaSemana <- weekdays(df_completo$Fecha, abbreviate = FALSE)

# Lista de meses en español
meses_espanol <- c("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", 
                   "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre")

# Interfaz de usuario (UI)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Aplicar estilos CSS personalizados
  tags$style(HTML("
    body {
      background-color: #666666;
      color: white;  /* Cambiar el color del texto para contraste */
    }
    .container-fluid {
      background-color: #666666;
    }
    .well {
      background-color: #666666;
      color: white;
    }
    .shiny-input-container {
      color: white;
    }
    .shiny-output-error {
      color: white;
    }
    .shiny-output-error:before {
      color: white;
    }
    h2 {
       text-align: center;  /* Centrar el título */
    }
    .custom-link {
                  color: white !important; /* Cambia 'red' por el color que prefieras */
                      text-decoration: none;
                  }
    .custom-link:hover {
                    color: blue !important; /* Cambia el color cuando el mouse esté sobre el enlace */
                  }
  ")),
  
  titlePanel(h2("Evaluación de restricciones de pesca en el puerto de Antequera - Chaco")),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Paso 1: Elegir span para LOESS
      tags$p("Primero se graficarán los valores registrados (nro. ind/día)."), # Texto explicativo
      tags$p("(espera un instante a verlos)"),
      tags$p("Luego debes seleccionar un valor de span (entre 0 y 1) para ajustar la suavización del gráfico con LOESS."), # Texto explicativo
      numericInput("span_loess", "Valor de span para LOESS:", 
                   value = 0.01, min = 0, max = 1, step = 0.01),
      tags$p("Elige un valor para ajustar la suavización del gráfico con LOESS."), # Texto explicativo
      
      actionButton("aplicar_loess", "Aplicar span LOESS"),  # Botón para aplicar el cambio de LOESS
      
      tags$br(),
      # Enlace a página externa con texto destacado
      tags$p("Para más información sobre el método LOESS, visita ",
             tags$a(href = "https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/loess", 
                    "la documentación de LOESS", target = "_blank"), "."), # Texto destacado con enlace
      
      
      # Espacio entre los gráficos
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$p("Sigue hacia abajo."),
      tags$br(),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$hr(style = "border: 2px solid black;"),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$p("La ´Veda tradicional´ considera los meses de noviembre y diciembre restringidos"),
      tags$br(),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$p("--Restricción similar a veda tradicional--"),
      tags$p("Ahora puedes elegir la cantidad de meses con restricción y cuándo comieza esa restricción."), # Texto explicativo
      
      # Paso 2: Elegir el número de meses de restricción
      numericInput("meses_restriccion", "Número de meses de restricción:", 
                   value = 1, min = 1, max = 12),
      
      # Paso 2.1: Elegir el mes de inicio
      selectInput("mes_inicio", "Mes de inicio para la restricción:", 
                  choices = meses_espanol),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$hr(style = "border: 2px solid black;"),
      tags$br(),
      
      tags$p("--Restricción como Veda extendida--"),
      tags$p("También pedes elegir que días de la semana restringes la pesca."), # Texto explicativo
      
      
      # Paso 3: Elegir los días de la semana que se restringen
      checkboxGroupInput("dias_restringidos", "Selecciona los días a restringir:",
                         choices = c("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado", "Domingo"),
                         selected = c("Sábado", "Domingo")),
      
      actionButton("aplicar", "Aplicar restricciones") # Botón para aplicar restricciones
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      # Gráfico comparativo
      plotOutput("grafico_comparativo", height = "400px"),
      
      # Espacio entre los gráficos
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$hr(),
      tags$hr(style = "border: 2px solid black;"),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      
      # Gráfico de barras
      plotOutput("barra_comparativa", height = "400px")
    )
  )
)

# Servidor (Server)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Datos originales sin LOESS
  df_completo_original <- reactive({
    df_completo
  })
  
  # Generar datos con el ajuste LOESS solo al presionar el botón
  df_completo_loess <- eventReactive(input$aplicar_loess, {
    fit_loess <- loess(`Numero de individuos` ~ as.numeric(Fecha), data = df_completo, span = input$span_loess)
    
    # Predecir valores y asegurar que no sean negativos
    df_completo %>%
      mutate(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS = pmax(0, predict(fit_loess, as.numeric(Fecha))))
  })
  
  # Calcular restricciones solo cuando se presiona el botón
  resultados_veda <- eventReactive(input$aplicar, {
    resultados <- list()
    
    total_individuos <- sum(df_completo_loess()$Numero_de_individuos_LOESS, na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Sin restricciones"]] <- total_individuos
    
    # Veda tradicional: noviembre y diciembre
    veda_tradicional <- df_completo_loess() %>%
      filter(month(Fecha) %in% c(11, 12)) %>%
      pull(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS)
    total_veda_tradicional <- total_individuos - sum(veda_tradicional, na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Veda tradicional"]] <- total_veda_tradicional
    
    # Restricción por meses (seleccionados por el usuario)
    mes_inicio_num <- match(input$mes_inicio, meses_espanol)
    meses_restriccion <- ((mes_inicio_num - 1 + 0:(input$meses_restriccion - 1)) %% 12) + 1
    veda_modificada <- df_completo_loess() %>%
      filter(month(Fecha) %in% meses_restriccion) %>%
      pull(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS)
    total_veda_modificada <- total_individuos - sum(veda_modificada, na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Veda tradicional con modificaciones"]] <- total_veda_modificada
    
    # Restricción por días seleccionados (transformamos los días a minúsculas para la comparación)
    dias_restringidos <- tolower(input$dias_restringidos)
    
    # Comparamos con los días de la semana del dataframe, también convertidos a minúsculas
    dias_permitidos <- !(tolower(df_completo_loess()$DiaSemana) %in% dias_restringidos)
    
    # Filtramos los datos permitidos y calculamos el total con la restricción por días
    total_veda_extendida <- sum(df_completo_loess() %>%
                                  filter(dias_permitidos) %>%
                                  pull(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS), na.rm = TRUE)
    resultados[["Veda extendida"]] <- total_veda_extendida
    
    resultados
  })
  
  # Gráfico comparativo de datos originales y LOESS
  output$grafico_comparativo <- renderPlot({
    plot_data <- df_completo_original()
    
    p <- ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Fecha)) +
      geom_point(aes(y = `Numero de individuos`, color = "Datos originales"), size = 2, alpha = 0.6) +
      labs(
        title = "Comparación de datos originales y ajuste LOESS",
        x = "Fecha",
        y = "Número de individuos",
        color = "Leyenda"
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
      scale_x_date(breaks = seq(min(df_completo$Fecha), max(df_completo$Fecha), by = "year"), date_labels = "%Y") +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("Datos originales" = "white", "Ajuste LOESS" = "blue"),
                         guide = guide_legend(title = NULL))+  # Ocultar título de la leyenda))
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1, color = "white"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12, color = "white"),
        legend.position = c(0.05, 0.95),
        legend.justification = c(0, 1),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "lightblue", # Background
                                         colour = 1),
      )
    
    # Agregar la línea de LOESS solo cuando se haya presionado el botón
    if (input$aplicar_loess > 0) {
      p <- p + geom_line(data = df_completo_loess(), aes(y = Numero_de_individuos_LOESS, color = "Ajuste LOESS"), size = 1.2)
    }
    
    p
  })
  
  # Gráfico de barras con los resultados de las restricciones
  output$barra_comparativa <- renderPlot({
    req(resultados_veda())  # Asegura que el cálculo de restricciones haya sucedido
    
    df_resultado <- data.frame(
      Tipo_Veda = factor(c("Sin restricciones", "Veda tradicional", 
                           "Veda tradicional con modificaciones", "Veda extendida"),
                         levels = c("Sin restricciones", "Veda tradicional", 
                                    "Veda tradicional con modificaciones", "Veda extendida")),
      Total_Individuos = unlist(resultados_veda())
    )
    
    # Calcular el porcentaje restante (100% - porcentaje actual)
    total_sin_restricciones <- df_resultado$Total_Individuos[df_resultado$Tipo_Veda == "Sin restricciones"]
    df_resultado <- df_resultado %>%
      mutate(Percentage_Restante = 100 - (Total_Individuos / total_sin_restricciones * 100))
    
    
    ggplot(df_resultado, aes(x = Tipo_Veda, y = Total_Individuos, fill = Tipo_Veda)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(Total_Individuos/1000, 0), "\n(", round(Percentage_Restante, 1), "% protegido)")), 
                vjust = 1.5, color = "black", size = 5) +
      labs(
        title = "Comparación del total de individuos capturados según tipo de veda",
        x = "Tipo de veda",
        y = "Número de individuos (x 1.000)",
        fill = "Tipo de veda"
      ) +
      scale_y_continuous(
        labels = function(x) x / 1000, 
        breaks = seq(0, max(df_resultado$Total_Individuos, na.rm = TRUE), by = 100000)
      ) +
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("Sin restricciones" = "lightblue", 
                                   "Veda tradicional" = "lightgreen",
                                   "Veda tradicional con modificaciones" = "lightcoral", 
                                   "Veda extendida" = "lightgoldenrod")) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "white"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12,color = "white"),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key.size = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#E5E5E5", # Background
                                         colour = 1)        # Border
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


I have searched for answers in this and several forums but cannot find solutions. Any help, thank you very much in advance.
and on the shinyapps.io website when I want to do the same, it doesn't happen, it looks like this:

Thanks!
I have re-edited and attached now a complete code with reproducible examples (only 500 data). This allows to interact with the two buttons of the app and reproduce the error.

I don't want to speculate on what's going on here without looking at it myself. Can you add data, so that your work is reproducible? Ideally you will use dput(head(df, 10)) or similar. If your data is proprietary, make fake data with the same format. To learn more about creating reproducible questions, read here: making R reproducible questions.

Thanks Kat, I hope it helps the way I edited the query.

Can you please take a look at what you've provided for data and run your app with it? First, it's a pack of 3 data frames, on a hunch I used final as df_completo.The only thing fed to the second plot is the factor Tipo_Veda and the selected days of the week in resultados_veda...I'm not sure if it's the data, app coding, or something else. For example, in geom_text you have a formula to divide the days of the week, as if it were a number (versus dividing the total count). Número de meses de restricción and Mes de inicio para la restricción aren't used in that plot - is that intentional?

It is intentional (the number of ind. and the percentage protected are shown). The values shown in geom_text are calculated each time the user interacts with the app, in results_veda inside eventReactive. Depending on the case, it calculates the individuals in the months or days selected by the user and subtracts them from the total number of individuals, which is obtained after the LOESS calculation.
The biological explanation is that from the total number of fish that could be caught, it subtracts those that would be caught in the restricted days or months.
Thank you Kat for your time.

I'm about 99% sure this has everything to do with locale: that system locale for shinyapps.io is not the same as your device-- more specifically the "LC_TIME" language isn't the same. When I run loess, weekdays are in English, which will never match your data. You could determine if language is the issue by adding a textOutput and rendertext with weekdays(Sys.Date()) in your app. Is the result in Spanish? The fix: add Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "es_ES") to the beginning of your .R file.

@Kat, I have tried everything you said, I discard that the code is taking wrongly the names of the days, it does everything in Spanish, with small letters. I also tried to solve my problem with Sys.setlocale(“LC_TIME”, “es_ES”) and variants of languages and even with "LC_ALL" “C” because in a shiny forum they mention it [link] (https://forum.posit.co/t/localized-formatting-of-a-date-when-you-cant-change-the-system-locale-on-shinyapps/83031), but the problem continues in the web.
I will continue investigating. Thank you very much.

If you would try one more thing for me--- add the library stringr and in server, in between the creation of  dias_permitidos & total_veda_extendida, add the following:  if(all(dias_permitidos)) { y <- c(Monday = "Lunes", Tuesday = "Martes", Wednesday = "Miércoles", Thursday = "Jueves", Friday = "Viernes", Saturday = "Sábado", Sunday = "Domingo") %>% tolower(); dp <- str_replace_all(df_completo_loess()$DiaSemana, y); dias_permitidos <- !(dp %in% dias_restringidos)} then run your app in shinyapps.io

Hi @Kat! this last solution has WORKED!!! I leave the link for a few days for you to see if you want link.
Even before trying what you suggest and thinking about one of your answers about the LC_time, I found another solution which was to assign numerical values to the days of the week, so that when I searched for them, I didn't do it with the names.
I paste the corrected code in a next comment:

Code I used to correct:
checkboxGroupInput("dias_restringidos", "Selecciona los días a restringir:", choices = list("Lunes" = 1, "Martes" = 2, "Miércoles" = 3, "Jueves" = 4, "Viernes" = 5, "Sábado" = 6, "Domingo" = 7), selected = c(6, 7)),
and then:
dias_restringidos <- input$dias_restringidos dias_permitidos <- !(df_completo_loess()$DiaSemana %in% dias_restringidos)  total_veda_extendida <- sum(df_completo_loess() %>% filter(dias_permitidos) %>% pull(Numero_de_individuos_LOESS), na.rm = TRUE)     resultados[["Veda extendida"]] <- total_veda_extendida

It looks great! Glad you've got it working.
